# Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm in the process of upgrading the gradle version in a project from 1.7 to 4.2.1.  I have set Intellij to import the gradle project but when I click Refresh all Gradle projects i get the following error

```
Gradle 'trunk-gradle-uplift' project refresh failed
Error:Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip'.
```

I have tried deleting everything in my %USER_HOME%/.gradle directory
Deleting the .gradle directory in the project.
Invalidating caches and restarting Intellij.

Any ideas how to fix this or even get some debug output as to why it failed?

Comment: Please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176336.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the issue was down to but uninstalling Intellij 2017.2.1 and installing Intellij 2017.2.5 seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: hi, 2017.2.1 and 2017.2.5, they the version numbers, of  what? thank you